# What is diffrence between `TextClock` and `DigitalClock`?

Tags: android, android-widget, clock

With the release of API level 17 I come to know about `TextClock` widget how it is different than that of Digital clock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DigitalClock` is deprecated with the release of API level 17. Moreover `TextClock` is recommended to be used while working on the applications with API level 17.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.